Unable to login - critical error
when trying to login I am facing There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.. I turned on debug and now I see this error
[26-Apr-2024 22:26:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "WPE_APIKEY" in /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/plugin.php:784
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/plugin.php(478): WpeCommon->set_wpe_auth_cookie()
#1 /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): WpeCommon->wp_hook_init('')
#2 /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#3 /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-settings.php(643): do_action('init')
#5 /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-config.php(98): require_once('/home2/uniam202...')
#6 /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home2/uniam202...')
#7 /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home2/uniam202...')
#8 /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home2/uniam202...')
#9 {main}
  thrown in /home2/uniam2022/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/plugin.php on line 784

May I ask if anyone has any suggestions on how to get around this?

It appears that one of WP Engine's mu-plugins is being run on an environment that is not WP Engine? If that's true, then removing the mu-plugin fully (and other WPE plugins) from your environment is the solution.

It hasn't moved environments at all. The only thing that was change was directory names.

Is the site hosted on WP Engine?
